# Pine: bug with the label.new function

Tags: pine-script

If you execute this code on RUNEUSD:

```
//@version=5
indicator("MA", "", true)

if (bar_index > 5000 and bar_index < 5800)
    label.new(bar_index, open,"", yloc = yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.blue, size = size.normal)
    
plot(na, "Zero line", color.gray)
```

you will notice blue arrows appearing below the bars (between bars 5000 and 5800).

But if you change the range with 4000 and 5000 like so:

```
if (bar_index > 4000 and bar_index < 5000)
```

No bar will appear at all!

I really cannot understand why, any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do appear but they don't start at index #4000. That is because you can only have a limited amount of labels on your chart. Default value is 50.

If you want to increase that add `max_labels_count=500` to your `indicator()` call.

```
indicator("MA", "", true, max_labels_count=500)
```

Your code:
[image]

With `max_labels_count=500`
[image]

The separate chart plots `bar_index`.